# Ajax load function not working in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, xml

**problem has been fixed. thanks a lot every one.**

i was trying to run that file directly offline instead of web server, by putting that file on web server(xampp server) it started working.

I am trying to load bits of html data in another html file using ajax to load html documents, but its not working. well that was foolish of me :-P

```
<div id="css_change"></div><br />


<div id="menu_"><a href="calla.html">Opt 1</a> <a href="sunflowers.html">Opt 2</a> <a href="iris.html">Opt 3</a> <a href="alstromeria.html">Opt 4 </a></div>
<br />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>


$(document).ready(function(e) {

var $flowers = $('#menu_');

$('#menu_').find('a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var $desc = $('#css_change');

    switch($(this).attr('href')) {
        case 'calla.html' :
            $desc.load('text/lilies.html');
            break;
        case 'sunflowers.html' :
            $desc.load('text/sunflower.html');
            break;
        case 'iris.html' :
            $desc.load('text/irises.html');
            break;
        case 'alstromeria.html' :
            $desc.load('text/peruvian.html');
            break;
    }
});


});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And also I think `preventDefault();` function is not working.

I am trying to use ajax to load html bits from one document to another.
please help.

Comment: From which web server you run this? Jquery load is working only on webservers. Sometime you may test your file as a local web page.

Comment: as local webpage i am useing

Comment: Is the JavaScript actually running? What part is not working exactly? What do you see in the console when it runs?

Comment: If so you can't use Jquery load function to get a local file. It is used to initiate http request from a web server.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/administrator/Desktop/web%20page/text/sunflower.html. Received an invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.  this is a error which i am getting now.

Answer (score 0):

use 
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js
for $ define.

without http can cause problem.
e.preventDefault() prevents default values

Comment: `//` is valid. Only issue is if the file is loaded with the file protocol.

Comment: i tryed that.. thanx but still the same. its showing me this error in debug panel XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/administrator/Desktop/web%20page/text/sunflower.html. Received an invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 0):

i got the solution. i was previewing those files offline. now after trying every thing. i just moved all the files into a web server and tried them. waala it started working. thanx everyone for your efforts.

ohh yes few changes did help me. thanx @SuperOV for

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js for $ define.
```

that worked.

Answer (score -1):

I've fixed the code using **'#menu_ a'** directly instead of find a, and **return false** instead of e.preventDefault.

Check this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $flowers = $('#menu_');

    $('#menu_ a').on('click', function(){

        var $desc = $('#css_change');

        switch($(this).attr('href')) {
            case 'calla.html' :
                $desc.load('text/lilies.html');
            break;
            case 'sunflowers.html' :
                $desc.load('text/sunflower.html');
            break;
            case 'iris.html' :
                $desc.load('text/irises.html');
            break;
            case 'alstromeria.html' :
                $desc.load('text/peruvian.html');
            break;
        }

    return false;

    });

});
```

Comment: Nop. not working. still the same. when i click that link it forwards me to that html page. but instead it should load html data in given div tag.

Comment: hmmm .. it works for me http://jsfiddle.net/s7FY7/, do you have any other javascript in your page ?

Comment: Can you share your code using jsfiddle or codepen.io ?